# Its showing me error when i try to use csv.writer() in python claiming that the writer function does not exist in csv module what should i do

Tags: python, csvwriter

Here is my code:

```
import csv
def addr():
    with open('csvfile.csv','a',newline='') as f:
        w=csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
        tid=int(input('Teacher ID: '))
        nm=input('Enter Name: ')
        mo=int(input('Mobile Number: '))
        w.writerow(tid,nm,mo)
def countr():
    with open('csvfile.csv') as f:
        c=csv.rowcount
        print('Number of records:',c)
while True:
    addr()
    if input('Do you Wish to Continue? (Y/N): ').lower() in ('n','no'):
        break
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpfdW.png)

It showed no error when I tried to use the normal file.write()

Comment: Looks like you named your own program csv.py, and try to import from csv. Change the name to something different.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)